# Rails 5 + Shrine + Polymorphic model + Pretty Location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, file-upload, shrine

I'm using Shrine for direct uploads to S3 and I'm trying to user the `pretty_location` plugin to set the location in my S3 bucket.

I have a document model has the `file_data`text attribute and is connected to a FileUploader:

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :documentable, polymorphic: true
  include FileUploader[:file]

  validates :file, presence: true
end
```

Other models are associated with the document model through the following concern:

```
module Documentable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_one :document, as: :documentable, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :document, allow_destroy: true
  end
end
```

This is my FileUploader:

```
class FileUploader < Shrine
  Attacher.promote { |data| PromoteJob.perform_later(data) }
  Attacher.delete { |data| DeleteJob.perform_later(data) }

  plugin :upload_options, cache: {acl: "public-read"}
  plugin :upload_options, store: {acl: "public-read"}
  plugin :logging, logger: Rails.logger
  plugin :pretty_location
  plugin :processing
  plugin :delete_promoted
  plugin :recache
  plugin :restore_cached_data
  plugin :delete_raw
  plugin :validation_helpers

  def generate_location(io, context = {})
    # do something depending on context[:record].documentable
  end
end
```

When uploading files from the user's filesystem via the client browser through nested attributes all works as expected and I'm able to generate a pretty location in my S3 bucket.

However, I have another model where I am trying to upload to S3 a PDF file which is generated in the backend with the following setup.

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :documents, as: :documentable, dependent: :destroy
end
```

The Invoice model doesn't use the concern as I want it to connect to the polymorphic document with a `has_many` association.

```
class Api::V1::InvoicesController < Api::V1::BaseController
  def upload_pdf
    pdf = InvoicePdf.new(@invoice)
    attachment = pdf.render
    file = StringIO.new(attachment)
    file.class.class_eval { attr_accessor :original_filename, :content_type }
    file.original_filename = "invoice_#{@invoice.reference}.pdf"
    file.content_type = "application/pdf"
    @document = @invoice.documents.new(file: file)
    if @document.save
      render "documents/show.json", status: :created
    else
      render json: { errors: @document.errors }, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
end
```

The upload works fine and I am able to upload the PDF to my S3 bucket, but I am not able to generate a pretty location because when I'm inside the `generate_location` method the `context[:record]` both the `documentable_type` and the `documentable_id` are `nil`.

This is a strange behaviour as in the rails console I am able to see that the association is correctly set after the upload has been done (without pretty_location) by running `Invoice.last.documents.file.url`.

I have tried creating the document record in different ways, have tried using the same `documentable` concern that works for other models but the result is alway the same and I have run out of ideas.

Does anyone have a clue why the `documentable_type` and `documentable_id` are not being passed into the `context` object inside the FileUploader?

Answer (score 1):

The above setup actually works. I was using a breakpoint inside the `generate_location` FileUploader method and the api was breaking because that method was returning nil.

After fixing that, the first time it ran `documentable` was still nil but the method would run a second time with the `documentable` attributes present.

```
def generate_location(io, context = {})
  return "" unless context[:record].documentable
  path =  if context[:record].documentable_type == "SomeClass"
            # do something
          elsif context[:record].documentable_type == "OtherClass"
            # do something else
          else
            # do something else
          end
  return path
end
```